# What is this squiggly trace for?

Tags: pcb, dac, inductance, serpentine-trace

[image: macro shot of a PCB with a squiggly trace on it]

It's on pin 14, which is the master clock input (MCLK) of a [WM8761: Low cost stereo DAC](http://www.wolfsonmicro.com/products/dacs/WM8761/).  I'm guessing it's meant to act as a small inductor?  But why would you want that on a clock input?

Comment: Datasheet at http://www.wolfsonmicro.com/documents/uploads/data_sheets/en/WM8761.pdf

Comment: just to be clear, the trace does not form any sort of loop, and therefore has negligible inductance relative to a straight path between the components.

Comment: It's there to draw attention away from the two mistakenly-routed, yellow wires on the top of the board.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's a serpentine track. They are often used where equal track lengths are required with high-speed designs. In this case it is probably used to implement a very short delay.

Comment: They're everywhere on computer motherboards, because they use lots of high speed busses. Take a look!

Comment: 20 ms is 50 hz. I think you mean 20ns.

Comment: Apparently related terms: "skew minimization", "skew control", "serpentine delay", and you can do a trombone shape instead?

Comment: That trace doesn't look like it's part of a bus...so how would it be used for matching propagation delays?

Comment: @ajs410 - The other traces may be on the other side of the board, or on internal layers. Remember, in this context, "Bus" basically means any place with more than one high speed data signals. It can be as few as two traces (Data, clock).

Comment: @endolith, you can do other shapes, but you generally don't want the very beginning of the trace running too close to the very end, since they will couple together capacitively.

Comment: @ajs410: There are other DACs on the board, also with these, of different shapes.

Comment: @ajs410: My guess would be that the device producing the data and clock for the device switches both simultaneously, and the squiggle helps ensure that the proper signal is registered first.  Though that would seem an awfully short squiggle to have much effect.